# The new implicit authentication dialog doesn't handle comma-delimited scopes

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2.2, authentication, oauth2

The [authentication docs](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) state that the [`scopes` parameter](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication#scope) of the URL to which a user should be directed to, for implicit authentication, should be a list of scopes that are delimited by either commas or spaces.

While both delimiting options worked with the old one, **delimiting with commas doesn't work with the new authentication dialog**.

When delimited **with commas** (as `scope=read_inbox,no_expiry,write_access,private_info`) or by the HTML-encoded `,` character `%2C`, the authentication dialog reads,

[image: Bad result]
          <sup>(Incorrect)</sup>

When delimited **with spaces** (as `scope=read_inbox no_expiry write_access private_info`), it reads,

[image: Correct result]
          <sup>(Correct)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to have been silently fixed, sometime in the last year.

Now, both:

- `https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=1515&scope=read_inbox,write_access,private_info&redirect_uri=https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success` (commas)
  And:
- `https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=1515&scope=read_inbox%20write_access%20private_info&redirect_uri=https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success` (spaces)

Are mapped to:
  `https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=1515&accountId=131474&scope=private_info+write_access+read_inbox...`

And yield the same, correct, results:

[image: Correct permissions]